# Cannot access pxToRem function in Material-ui for theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/) with React.  I'm trying to theme my application. Unfortunately the material-ui library provides a light-theme.js example (via some means), but the material-ui theming components rely on functions within the theme.  Specifically the [theme.typography.pxToRem function for calculating rem conversions.](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createTypography.js)

How do I provide access to those functions on in my own theme?

Now, I would go through the steps of reimplementing pxToRem and similar on my theme, but it seems very unlikely that others have done that due to the nested closure used.  What are others doing to access functions on the material-ui theme?

Comment: have you used createMuiTheme ?

Comment: if you wrap your component with `withStyle` HOC then you could access it using `theme.typography.pxToRem` in the styles object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Material UI gives us access to override css classes by using `createMuiTheme`. You have to pass down theme to your app with `MuiThemeProvider`. Here is the way to implement it:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const fontSize = 14, // px
// Tell Material-UI what's the font-size on the html element.
// 16px is the default font-size used by browsers.
const htmlFontSize = 16,
const coef = fontSize / 14;

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    pxToRem: size => `${(size / htmlFontSize) * coef}rem`,
  },
});
```

in you render method:

```
 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

PS. I have tested it. it's working like a charm.

Please ask me any question regarding this. Happy to help

Comment: Hi Sakhi, can you please explain why coef?

Comment: I was thinking this through several times before I got it. The coef is used to maintain the relative size between the variants if you configure the fontSize in the theme. e.g. default fontSize is 14. body1 size is 16. body2 size is 14 = fontSize. If you change the fontSize to 17, body2 = 17 and you need to change the body1 size accordingly by several percent (which are represented by coef).